# how to unset current iteration in tfs2013?

Tags: tfs

Recently I created a new iteration and set it as a team current one, but unfortunatly we have one project team that is divided into smaller tasks teams.
That means - all people can see only **"current iteration"** instead of areas that there were working on.

I know that this problem is connected with fact that we haven't got setup subteams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage the permissions for each iteration/area node.

Please following below steps to unset that:

1. Create sub-teams/user groups (You can also set permission for each team member separately if you do not want to create subteams.)
2. Select/create iteration/area (enable the checkbox in front of the
   iteration) to display them in backlog tab.
3. [Restrict access to work items assigned to an area or an iteration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181692%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Restrict%20access%20to%20work%20items%20assigned%20to%20an%20area%20or%20an%20iteration)
   for each sub-team.

After completing the permission settings, each sub-team members will in areas that there were working on.

That's not possible get to "pristine" settings, because you have worked on the iteration, unless you also reset all the works which done on this iteration, eg change all the workitem iteration path or delete the workitems and unset all the permission/policy settings, etc. I think it's not necessary, you can just create a new iteration for further actions.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, my question is how to revert action: "set as current iteration"

Comment: @profesor79 Just change the iteration date to old, set other iteration date fo current.

Comment: thanks for the update, but what I would to get to "pristine" settings that unset any iteration in particular project (imagine that no one set any in the past...)

Comment: @profesor79 That's not possible, because you have worked on the iteration, unless you also reset all the works which done on this iteration, eg change all the workitem iteration path or delete the workitems and unset all the permission/policy settings, etc. I think it's not necessary, you can just create a new iteration for further actions.